# What does it mean by overloading an operator

Tags: java

In a book am reading about String concatenation, they say that the '+' operator is overloaded in java (the only overloaded operator).How is it overloaded?

Comment: 12+13 and 12+"test" is interpreted differently

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Overloading for + operator means that there are two different operations depending on the parameters.

- For numbers + is an addition
- For String + is a concatenation